# Java + Maven + make executable jar + Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, maven, jar, slf4j, executable-jar

I have a problem with executing a jar.

When I do:

```
mvn package
```

I get my jar in the target folder but I get a NoClassDefFoundError on the LoggerFactory of slf4j api when I want to run it.

This is my POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.t0tec.main.Start</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Any idea what is wrong with the configuration?

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I recommend you use https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/ to make your jar with dependencies. I solved it somehow using maven assembly: https://github.com/t0tec/racing-2D/blob/master/desktop-app/racingDesktop/pom.xml

Comment: thanks i'll give it a try

Comment: As suggested maven-shade-plugin worked for me,

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `slf4j-api`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added the dependency and cleaned the project and did a maven update but still the same error.